# How do I redirect stdout/stderr when also using the input redirection operator `<`?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I have a bash script that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 = database dump
# $2 = mysql connect command
$2 < $1
```

And that last part prints output to stdout & stderr that I don't want. However, I don't know how best to do a `> /dev/null 2>&1` style redirect because of how I'm already doing an input redirection.

Comment: BTW, quotes matter. `< $1` will fail if your filename contains spaces, whereas `< "$1"` will not. (Passing a command in a single argument is almost always buggy; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for a full description of why)

Comment: Good practice is something like: `dump=$1; shift; "$@" <"$dump"`, passing your command as a series of separate arguments; that is, something like `./yourscript dumpfile mysql -u username` -- that way any of those arguments (the filename, the other arguments to MySQL, etc) can have quoting/whitespace/etc. and still be handled correctly.

Answer (score 3):

**The order does not matter.** You can put `< "$1"` before or after `>/dev/null 2>&1`:

- `"$2" < "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1`
- `"$2" >/dev/null 2>&1 < "$1"`

As Charles Duffy pointed out, **don't forget to put your `$1` and `$2` variables inside quotes**.

Comment: Some of the order matters: `2>&1` still has to follow `>/dev/null`.

Comment: *nod*. Hopefully the OP isn't doing something like `./scriptname dumpfile "mysql -u username"` -- but in that case they've got problems that call for a bigger fix (ie. changing to `./scriptname dumpfile mysql -u username`). Without detailed usage, though, it's hard to do anything but speculate.